# Bootstrap 4 Grid Layout with Form

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am making simple form and control side by side with full width control but it is not working and if I put col-sm-xx than it will break and to another line. So how can I make them in one line with full column width

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="dropdown" id="dpLocation">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            Location
                        </button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <a class="dropdown-item">Sharq</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item">Shuwaikh</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item">Hawally</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item">Farwaniya</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item">Hawally</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile" class="form-control" id="txMobile" minlength="8" maxlength="8" pattern="\d*">
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <a>
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" style="font-size:24px;color:#fff"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: @AG_BOSS let me try and get back to you

Comment: @AG_BOSS Check my updated image

Comment: @AG_BOSS There is no `col-xs` in Bootstrap 4. It's just `col`. See: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#grid-options

Comment: ok understood @Klooven

Comment: @AG_BOSS margin-right is also not good idea as it will give different output in different mobile

Comment: where did i tell @Milind ?

Comment: @AG_BOSS .items{
  margin-right: 10px;
}

Comment: my other post (Pradeep)? is it that one?

Comment: i have edited that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `col-auto` to minimize the width of the dropdown button and icon, and then `col` to make the input fill width...

https://www.codeply.com/go/hJcCGGUnpC

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
        <div class="col-auto">
            <div class="dropdown" id="dpLocation">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    Location
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item">Sharq</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item">Shuwaikh</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item">Hawally</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item">Farwaniya</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item">Hawally</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile" class="form-control" id="txMobile" minlength="8" maxlength="8" pattern="\d*">
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            <a>
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" style="font-size:24px;"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your reply is okay but there is not space between the elements. I want some space between them

Comment: Just remove `no-gutters` from the `.row`. I thought you wanted no space.

Comment: ok removing gutters works but can we reduce white space now it have lot of space :(

Comment: Use the [spacing utils for padding](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/). For example, `px-1`.  This is outside the scope of the original question which was how to keep the form inline. Please update the question with the spacing requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following snippet

```css
.items{
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-sm-4 items">
      <div class="dropdown" id="dpLocation">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            Location
                        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item">Sharq</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">Shuwaikh</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">Hawally</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">Farwaniya</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item">Hawally</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile" class="form-control" id="txMobile" minlength="8" maxlength="8" pattern="\d*">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <a>
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" style="font-size:24px;color:#fff"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The difference is i think in div class="col" right?

Comment: what are the other dependencies your having @Milind
AG_BOSS yes seems to be. because it works in this snippet though

Comment: Sorry it is working but they don't have space between each other how can we do that

Comment: can you show a screenshot, im not clear what you meant @Milind

Comment: maybe add some margin between then by declaring a class for css?

Comment: Check now. I have updated the answer by adding a margin-right to the button by creating a css class called items and referring it in the button @Milind